# Sorting CSV file column value based on column headers

Tags: perl

Hi am newbie fir perl scripting, i need a help implement a logic for sorting CSV file header based column values,.

Example:

```
S.NO,NAME,S2,S5,S3,S4,S1
1,aaaa,88,99,77,55,66
2,bbbb,66,77,88,99,55
3,cccc,55,44,77,88,66
4,dddd,77,55,66,88,99
```

now i want to sort this file as below..

s.no,s2,s4,s5,s1,s0,name => that's how i want is as i defined order of headers like s.no,name,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5 and it's respective whole columns values also should change based on header exchange, how to do it perl this one...?

That's the required output is like following bellow,

S.NO,NAME,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5
1,aaaaaaa,66,88,77,55,99
2,bbbbbbb,55,66,88,77,99
3,ccccccc,66,55,77,88,44
4,ddddddd,99,77,66,88,55

or what the order i want in column headers, like below.

S.NO,NAME,S5,S4,S3,S2,S1 -> like as per my requirement i need to re-order my columns header and it's respective columns value also..

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;
my $file = 'a1.csv';

my $size = 3;

my @files;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, sep_char => ';' });
open my $in, "<:encoding(utf8)", $file or die "$file: $!";
while (my $row = $csv->getline($in)) {
    if (not @files) {
        my $file_counter = int @$row / $size;
        $file_counter++ if @$row % $size;
        for my $i (1 .. $file_counter) {
            my $outfile = "output$i.csv";
            open my $out, ">:encoding(utf8)", $outfile or die "$outfile: $!";
            push @files, $out;
        }
    }

    my @fields = @$row;
    foreach my $i (0 .. $#files) {
        my $from = $i*$size;
        my $to   = $i*$size+$size-1;

        $to      = $to <= $#fields ? $to : $#fields;
        my @data = @fields[$from .. $to];

        $csv->print($files[$i], \@data);
        print {$files[$i]} "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `sep_char => ';'` Should be `sep_char => ','`  (based on your sample file)?

Comment: *"now i want to sort this file as: .s.no,s2,s4,s5,s1,s0,name"*. What is `s4` and `s0`? There is no column headers in the original csv with name `s4` and `s0`.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use Text::CSV qw();
my @headers = qw(s.no name s1 s2 s3 s4 s5);
my $csv_in = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1, auto_diag => 1});
my $csv_out = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1, auto_diag => 1});
open my $in, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', 'a1.csv';
open my $out, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', 'output1.csv';
$csv_in->header($in);
$csv_out->say($out, [@headers]);
while (my $row = $csv_in->getline_hr($in)) {
    $csv_out->say($out, [$row->@{@headers}]);
}
```

Comment: Hi daxim, it giving only the single row of headers only, but i need respective header column values also, like S1,S2,S3,S4,S5 and it's whole column values that's next row, 2nd row values 66,55,77,99, then 3rd row values bbbb,55,99,88,77, like that all row values also should exchange

Comment: @ShanmugamE, did you actually run the code? It does reorder the values. The hashref slice in the last line of code is responsible.

Comment: while (my $row = $csv_in->getline_hr($in)) {
 15     $csv_out->say($out, [$row->@{@headers}]);
 16     }
while am running this code am getting following error.
"Array found where operator expected at solution.pl line 15, at end of line
 (Missing operator before ?)
syntax error at solution.pl line 15, near "->@"
Execution of solution.pl aborted due to compilation errors."
so removed @ at 15 line, 
$csv_out->say($out, [@headers]);
 14 while (my $row = $csv_in->getline_hr($in)) {
 15     $csv_out->say($out, [$row->{@headers}]);
 16     }
~

Comment: You can either upgrade your Perl (it's already so old it's unsupported), or change the hashref slice syntax to `@{$row}{@headers}`

Comment: Hi daxm, if i add like below, while (my $row = $csv_in->getline_hr($in)) {
 15     $csv_out->say($out, [@{$row}{@headers}]);
 16     }
am getting output file as simply empty rows with comma separation, it's not giving values
S.NO,NAME,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5
,,,,,,
,,,,,,
,,,,,,
,,,,,,

Comment: You changed the capitalisation of the column names. You had lower-case column names in the first version of the question.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you, but if i want sort upper case headers like "NAME", or mixing letters like "Name" means how i can use this script, what to change in it to work for mixing letters or upper case or lower case letters means,

Comment: Change line 6 where the header names (and output order) are defined. If that's not what you mean, then you need to [open a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Ok, and another one issue am getting following error, "# CSV_PP ERROR: 1012 - INI - the header contains an empty field @ rec 1 pos 0 
INI - the header contains an empty field" when my CSV file column headers are like s5,s4,s.no,s2,s3,s1, - that's when last s1 completes with "," it's throwing this error, why? how to fix that please.

Comment: Remove the last comma after s1. It's not fair that you keep changing the input.

Comment: sorry for inconvenient, actually based on excel sheet am generating this input csv file, so while parsing data from excel to csv, that comma operator getting place at end of the row line, by default, initially i didn't mention it sorry, so input csv file values ends with "," only like s1, how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The handy [Text::AutoCSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::AutoCSV) module lets you rearrange the column order as a one-liner:

```
$ perl -MText::AutoCSV -e 'Text::AutoCSV->new(in_file=>"in.csv",out_file=>"out.csv",out_fields=>["SNO","NAME","S1","S2","S3","S5"])->write()'
$ cat out.csv
s.no,name,s1,s2,s3,s5
1,aaaa,66,55,77,99
2,bbbb,55,99,88,77
3,cccc,66,88,77,44
4,dddd,99,88,66,55
```

I'm not sure what your actual desired order of fields is because you have two and both of them include columns that aren't in the sample input file (It has two s2 columns; is one of them supposed to be s4?), but you should get the idea. Column names have to be all caps with special characters like . removed, but the actual names are used for the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $eix = "001"; $csv_in->header ($in, munge_column_names => sub { s/^$/"E".$eix++/er/; });
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but include an explanation what this code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality and more likely to attract upvotes.