# Sort CSV column values based on headers in perl

Tags: perl

I have large csv file containing 350 fields. The headers and values should be arranged based on headers in another csv file.

To try out on smaller case, I have below code-
reference headers {A B C D}

```
use File::Basename;
use Array::Utils qw(:all); 
use Text::CSV;
my @headers = qw(A B C D);
my $csv_in = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1, auto_diag => 1});
my $csv_out = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1, auto_diag => 1});
open my $in, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', 'test.csv';
open my $out, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', 'test_out.csv';

$csv_in->header($in);  
$csv_out->say($out, [@headers]);
while (my $row = $csv_in->getline_hr($in)) {
  $csv_out->say($out, [@{$row}{@headers}]);
}
```

It is printing headers correctly, but values of other next rows are empty

Inputs file -

A,B,D,C

1,2,4,3

Expected output -

A,B,C,D

1,2,3,4

Current output -

A,B,C,D

,,,

Can anyone help me here to fix this?

Comment: [You copied the code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57325234/4251338)

Comment: Yes it is. Do you know where is the mistake in the code?

Comment: Without seeing the input we can't help you much.

Comment: input file test.csv is as below-  1st row,A,B,D,C 2nd row -1,2,4,3

Comment: You need to put your sample input and desired output in the question itself, not a comment. (Though I stand by my answer in the question you copied your code from)

Comment: Quote: _The headers and values should be arranged based on headers in another csv file._ - but you define headers in the code, it is not obvious what you read from `$in` and how you use it. A sample of input and output would be nice, without this data we are at guess point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I had another version of perl and Text::CSV. This worked for me:

```
$csv_in->column_names($csv_in->getline($in));
```

instead of

```
$csv_in->header($in);
```

My version lacked the function `header`. But I think, the crucial point is that you must define the column names for the input CSV file.